# ansible ec2_group module failed to create new security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, ec2-api-tools, ansible

I have recently started learning ansible so it might sound like a noob question. I wrote a simple playbook(example.yml) which will create a security group in AWS ec2 using ansible's ec2_group module.

The playbook is -

```
---
- name: Add a security group to ec2
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  tasks:
    local_action:
      module: ec2_group
      name: TestSecurityGroup001
      description: A new ec2 security group via ansible playbook
      region: us-east-1
      rules:

        - proto: tcp
          from_port: 80
          to_port: 80
          cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0

        - proto: tcp
          from_port: 22
          to_port: 22
          cidr_ip: 10.0.0.0/8

        - proto: udp
          from_port: 10050
          to_port: 10050
          cidr_ip: 10.0.0.0/8

        - proto: udp
          from_port: 10051
          to_port: 10051
          group_id: abc123
```

When I do

```
$ ansible-playbook example.yml

PLAY [Add a security group to ec2] ******************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Now when I list the security groups

```
$ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region=us-east-1 --group-name=TestSecurityGroup001
$ A client error (InvalidGroup.NotFound) occurred: The security group 'TestSecurityGroup001' does not exist
```

Can someone tell me what should be done to fix this.

Comment: Beside using cli, do you see that group if you use web console?

Comment: When I use euca2ool api, the group does not show either...Is there any work around for this..??

Comment: It does not show up when you use `aws ec2 describe-security-groups` command, but does show up in web console? If so then this sounds like a bug with AWS and you should report it to them..

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a `-` in your playbook, ansible expects tasks to be a list. Try this:

```
 tasks:
    - local_action:
```

instead of:

```
 tasks:
    local_action:
```

Comment: Tried but in vain....At last I modified my playbook and used the 'command' module of ansible to execute aws cli create-security-group command to add a security group.